# Crystal Reports: issue with multiple parameter values in record selection

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a report with:

Parameter: Risk Criteria / Type: String / List of Values: Static

Has the following values

```
BBORSM, DDMAPS, DLSE, HDCP, PCEOL, SCILI, ALL
```

Allow Multiple Values: `True`

Each Risk has its own column within the database table and the value will either be null/empty or "Y"

In the Record Selection

I need it to be able to display one risk, two risks, three risks and so on it depends what the user has picked. The user can select the risks in any order.

So if they select the first two risks it should bring back.

`BBORSM` on its own, `DDMAPS` on it own or `BBORSM` and `DDMAPS`

So far I have got.

```
(
numbervar NoOfValues := count({?Risk Criteria});
numbervar i := 1;

for i := 1 to NoOfValues do(
((if ({?Risk Criteria}[i]) = "BBOSRM" then {Table.BBOSRM} = 'Y' else true)and
(if {?Risk Criteria}[i] = "DDMAPS" then {Table.DDMAPS} = 'Y' else true))
)//end of for loop 
)//end of risks
```

So it takes the value from the array, if that value was selected then true else false.

At the minute it doesn't bring back any records, when I take the for loop out it can work ok for One risk or All risks.

Comment: are you able to find the solution?